# Find out in which commit each file changed last?

Tags: git, github

I want to know the commit when each file in my repo (or subdirectory of my repo) was most recently changed.

`git log -p some_file.txt` will show me the commit history for a single file.

However, I want just the commit hash in which it changed along with the filename (ideally on one line). In addition, I want to do this for a directory of files (or, the whole repo).

So essentially, I'm looking for output similar to:

```
./file1.txt  hash1
./file2.txt  hash1
./file3.txt  hash2
./file4.txt  hash3
./file5.txt  hash2
```

where hash[n] is the hash of the commit where the file was last modified.

I tried `git log --pretty=oneline -p file1.txt` but the `--pretty` was ignored in this case. Also I want to include the file name in the output instead of the commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some scripting you can use this command to get the output that you are looking for:

`find . -type f | egrep -v "(git)" | xargs -I {} git log -1 --pretty=format:'%H {}' {}`

This finds all the files in your folder, filters out the git directory and then calls `git log` with the format that you are looking for (though this one has the hash first)

Comment: Rather than piping into `egrep`, `find` can filter out the `.git` directory itself: `find . -type f -not -path '*/.git/*' ...`.

Comment: True, I forget about using that.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way `git` stores commits and the files they contain (a commit contains a tree that contains files and other trees, but these are all forward pointers) there is no easy reference from a file back to the tree(s) containing it, nor from a tree to the other tree(s) or commit(s) containing it). As a result, there is no simple way to do this in `git` alone.

That's not to say it can't be done, though - it will just take some scripting. As you've noted, one approach would be to simply do a `git log` to find the last place each individual file was changed - possibly something like `git log -1 --pretty=format:%H -- <filename>`. The opposite approach would be to use `git ls-tree` to get the current SHA1 for each file, then a combination of `git log`, `git show` and `git ls-tree` to map each file to the tree(s) containing it, and then map those trees back to the most recent commit containing them. I suspect the first approach will be much easier, although the second approach would probably perform better, if you loaded arrays of the various hashes into e.g. Python arrays...

Comment: OK, so your suggestion to use log with the format %H could work. Obviously this could get pretty slow, but I could iterate through a directory and run that for each file and generate the list that way. Thanks!